# Webpage doesn't work in Firefox but works in Chrome and Torch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, firefox

I have used HTML, CSS, JS (& jQuery) and PHP to make this site. It works flawlessly in Chrome and Torch. But doesn't work in Firefox. Contents in div3_iframe1 and div4_iframe1 are not displayed.......

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Jeewya Medical Center</title>
    <link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function resize(obj){
            document.getElementById(obj).setAttribute("height",0);
            document.getElementById(obj).setAttribute("height",frames[obj].document.body.scrollHeight);
        }

        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#loading').hide();
        });

        function register(){
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeIn("fast");
            document.getElementById("div3_iframe1").setAttribute("src","registration system 2.4/index.php");
        }

        function appointments(){
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeIn("fast");
            document.getElementById("div3_iframe1").setAttribute("src","appointments/appointments.php");
        }

        function reports(){
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeIn("fast");
            document.getElementById("div3_iframe1").setAttribute("src","reports/index.php");
        }

        function analyze(){
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeIn("fast");
            document.getElementById("div3_iframe1").setAttribute("src","analyze/index.php");
        }

        function inquire(){
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeIn("fast");
            document.getElementById("div3_iframe1").setAttribute("src","inquire/index.php");
        }

        function home(){
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeIn("fast");
            document.getElementById("div3_iframe1").setAttribute("src","home/home.php");
        }

        function prescriptions(){
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#div3_iframe1").fadeIn("fast");
            document.getElementById("div3_iframe1").setAttribute("src","prescriptions/index.php");
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">

        <div id="loading">
            <img id="loading-image" src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>

        <div id="LayoutDiv1">
            <iframe src="slider/index.html" style="width:1152px; height:200px;max-width:100%;overflow:hidden;border:none;padding:5px;margin:0 auto;display:block;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="LayoutDiv2">
            <!-- Button Set -->

            <img src="button set/register/1.png" style="z-index:-1; position:absolute;" width="175px" id="btn1" name="btn1"/>
            <img src="button set/register/text.png" onmouseover="btn1.src='button set/register/2.png'" onmouseout="btn1.src='button set/register/1.png'" onclick="register(); btn1.src='button set/register/3.png'" width="200px" id="text1"/>
            <br/>
            <img src="button set/appointments/1.png" style="z-index:-1; position:absolute;" width="175px" id="btn2" name="btn2"/>
            <img src="button set/appointments/text.png" onmouseover="btn2.src='button set/appointments/2.png'" onmouseout="btn2.src='button set/appointments/1.png'" onclick="appointments(); btn2.src='button set/appointments/3.png'" width="200px" id="text2"/>
            <br/>
            <img src="button set/reports/1.png" style="z-index:-1; position:absolute;" width="175px" id="btn3" name="btn3"/>
            <img src="button set/reports/text.png" onmouseover="btn3.src='button set/reports/2.png'" onmouseout="btn3.src='button set/reports/1.png'" onclick="reports(); btn3.src='button set/reports/3.png'" width="200px" id="text3"/>
            <br/>
            <img src="button set/prescriptions/1.png" style="z-index:-1; position:absolute;" width="175px" id="btn4" name="btn4"/>
            <img src="button set/prescriptions/text.png" onmouseover="btn4.src='button set/prescriptions/2.png'" onmouseout="btn4.src='button set/prescriptions/1.png'" onclick="prescriptions(); btn4.src='button set/prescriptions/3.png'" width="200px" id="text4"/>
            <br/>
            <img src="button set/analyze/1.png" style="z-index:-1; position:absolute;" width="175px" id="btn5" name="btn5"/>
            <img src="button set/analyze/text.png" onmouseover="btn5.src='button set/analyze/2.png'" onmouseout="btn5.src='button set/analyze/1.png'" onclick="analyze(); btn5.src='button set/analyze/3.png'" width="200px" id="text5"/>
            <br/>
            <img src="button set/inquire/1.png" style="z-index:-1; position:absolute;" width="175px" id="btn6" name="btn6"/>
            <img src="button set/inquire/text.png" onmouseover="btn6.src='button set/inquire/2.png'" onmouseout="btn6.src='button set/inquire/1.png'" onclick="inquire(); btn6.src='button set/inquire/3.png'" width="200px" id="text6"/>
            <br/>
            <img src="button set/home/1.png" style="z-index:-1; position:absolute;" width="175px" id="btn7" name="btn7"/>
            <img src="button set/home/text.png" onmouseover="btn7.src='button set/home/2.png'" onmouseout="btn7.src='button set/home/1.png'" onclick="home(); btn7.src='button set/home/3.png'" width="200px" id="text7"/>
            <br/>

            <!-- Button Set -->
        </div>

        <div id="LayoutDiv3">
            <iframe id="div3_iframe1" src="home/home.php" scrolling="auto" width="100%" frameBorder="0" onload="resize('div3_iframe1')" onblur="resize('div3_iframe1')"></iframe>
        </div>

        <div id="LayoutDiv4">
            <iframe id="div4_iframe1"src="Registration%20system%202.4/login.php" scrolling="auto" width="100%" frameBorder="0" onload="resize('div4_iframe1')" style="max-height:900px"></iframe>
            <div>
                <p><b>View location with Google Maps</b></p>
                    <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=211105280369292538191.0004ef7703137975a2b66&amp;gl=US&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=7.079269,79.859659&amp;spn=0,0&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>View <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=211105280369292538191.0004ef7703137975a2b66&amp;gl=US&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=7.079269,79.859659&amp;spn=0,0&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Jeewya Medical Center</a> in a larger map</small>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="LayoutDiv5">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "LayoutDiv5"</div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Any error in console? Does the iframe src correctly set on FF?

Comment: If `<script src="respond.min.js"></script>` use any jQuery method, it should be included after jQuery. But would be strange it works on chrome then

Comment: This website functions flawlessly in Opera, Torch, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround your jQuery functions (because they are in the head of the document) with a document ready handler -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // jQuery code here
});
```

Comment: As i see it, OP is not calling any method before DOM is ready

Comment: He may not be, but I have seen some funny behavior in FF that goes away when the doc ready handler is applied.

Comment: We do so much cross-browser testing every day that we find some of the oddest quirks, like this one. I had the same problem a couple of months ago even with the jQuery code at the bottom of the page. added the doc ready handler and BINGO - it worked. Now we just have everyone in the habit.

Comment: Your solution seems to work....but that disables function resize(obj). It doesn't work, meaning that the iframes are not resized.

Comment: Please give me another clue. This works perfectly in Chrome, Torch, Safari and Opera

Comment: There is no reason that the resize function would get disabled. Any errors in the console? You can wrap all of your JavaScript in the document ready handler, which may help.